# How can I set message encoding for a web reference

Tags: vb.net, console-application, web-reference

I've been given a service which I need to consume.  This service is only happy when added to the project as a 'web reference' and NOT a 'service reference'. When I add the reference, the app.config is modified as shown here...

```
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
        <section name="TestApp.My.MySettings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
<applicationSettings>
    <TestApp.My.MySettings>
        <setting name="TestApp_DemoService_Rfx" serializeAs="String">
            <value>https://www.mydemosourcesite.com:443/common/services/Rfx/</value>
        </setting>
    </TestApp.My.MySettings>
</applicationSettings>
```

I can consume the service fine, except that the response it's returning uses MTOM.  My question is - how can I configure this service to use MTOM for the message encoding.  If I were doing this with a service reference, I'd do this...

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="RfxSOAP" messageEncoding="Mtom">
                <security mode="Transport" />
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="https://www.mydemosourcesite.com:443/common/services/Rfx/" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="RfxSOAP" contract="DemoService.Rfx" name="RfxSOAP" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Sadly though, I'm not using a service reference and no idea how to get this configured for a web reference!  This is in VB and .NET 4.

All help appreciated!